# Can I use both the RSA 2-Factor PAM and an Active Directory PAM at the same time?

Tags: linux, pam

Let's use the product formerly known as [Likewise](http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/) as an example. I can very easily install this on a Linux machine and join it to an Active Directory domain.

I can also use an RSA PAM module so that users are forced to authenticate with a 2-factor hardware token PIN and passcode, using a username that is known to the RSA authenticating server.

Can I use these two together? In other words, I guess what I'm asking is can I use two PAM modules at the same time?  (I'm not a Linux guy so take it easy on me please.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Linux PAM you can chain authentication modules. Just set all the necessary PAM-module you want to be checked to `required` in the appropriate configuration file.

From the documentation:

> When a server invokes one of the six PAM primitives, PAM retrieves the
>   chain for the facility the primitive belongs to, and invokes each of
>   the modules listed in the chain, in the order they are listed, until
>   it reaches the end, or determines that no further processing is
>   necessary (either because a binding or sufficient module succeeded, or
>   because a requisite module failed.) The request is granted if and only
>   if at least one module was invoked, and all non-optional modules
>   succeeded.

So if all authentication methodes must be successful, use `requisite`. However, if the first of two auth-methodes fails, it will terminate immediately.

If you want to hide the fact that some certain auth-methode failed, use `required`. Even if one module fails, it will continue to check other methodes, just to fail at the end.

If you only need one of those methodes to succeed (means: many may fail, only one successful auth is sufficient), use `sufficient`.

Refer to [Pam Chain Policies](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-pam.html#pam-chains-policies) for more details.

Comment: Fantastic answer, detailed and thorough and straight to the point. Would do business with again, A+++++++++++